# Unable to build Android using ionic

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I am trying to setup Ionic framework for developing android apps on my mac but I am having some problems in building android apps.
I have followed following procedure for installing ionic :

```
Run: "sudo npm install -g cordova"
Run: "sudo npm install -g ionic"
Run: “android” then install the following packages
Tools: Andoird SDK Tools, Android SDK Platform-tools, Android SDK Build-tools
Android 4.4.2 (API 19)
Extras: Android Support Library
```

My .bash file is like this :

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
export PATH=${JAVA_HOME}/bin:$PATH
export PATH=${PATH}:~/Library/Android/sdk/tools:~/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools
```

This is the error I am getting while building android app :

```
You have been opted out of telemetry. To change this, run: cordova telemetry on.

Running command: /Users/coderahul/sampleIonicApp/hooks/after_prepare/010_add_platform_class.js /Users/coderahul/sampleIonicApp


add to body class: platform-android

ANDROID_HOME=/Users/coderahul/Library/Android/sdk

JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk/Contents/Home



FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> failed to find target with hash string 'android-23' in: /Users/coderahul/Library/Android/sdk

* Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.


BUILD FAILED

Total time: 2.299 secs

Error: /Users/coderahul/sampleIonicApp/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> failed to find target with hash string 'android-23' in: /Users/coderahul/Library/Android/sdk

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Please install Android target: "android-23".

   Hint: Open the SDK manager by running: /Users/coderahul/Library/Android/sdk/tools/android
You will require:
1. "SDK Platform" for android-23
2. "Android SDK Platform-tools (latest)
3. "Android SDK Build-tools" (latest)
```

Comment: You doesn't seem to have install the right version of SDK platform (you said api 19), cordova is waiting for api 23. Just install this version

Comment: Update android SDK.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me just type this in your terminal "/Users/coderahul/Library/Android/sdk/tools/android" and proceed with the steps to download the sdk for android-23.

This happens because your device is using the higher version of OS than the sdk version